How to group a List<LineString> which are connected to each other to a “MultilineString” in NetTopologySuite
I'm using NetTopologySuite  and have a lot of lines in a List<LineString> and would like to group them in List<MultiLineString>. Every MultiLineString should contain the LineStrings which are connected to each other (i. e. share at least one Coordinate) or crossing each other.
I'm thinking of a method like:
List<MultiLineString> GroupLineStrings(List<LineString> lineStrings)
{
 multiLineStrings = new List<MultilineString>();
 
 ...
 
 return multiLineStrings;
}

Any suggestions in C#?
